# Get string from array and start loop

Tags: php, buddypress

I´m using this code to get all members of the groups, in which the logged-in user is member of.

Questions:

The $group_id is a string from an array. My problem is, there are more than one $value / group_id in the array. In this example group_id=5 and group_id=6
So how can I change the code to a loop (for e.g. with foreach) to list all members of all $value / group_id, in this example group_id=5 and group_id=6 ?

Thank you!

```
<?php 
    $user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
    $groups = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_ids( $user_id );      

    foreach ($groups as $type => $properties) { 
        foreach ($properties as $property => $value) { 
            $group_id = 'group_id='. ' ' .$value. ' '  .'&exclude_admins_mods=false';
        }
    }

if ( bp_group_has_members($group_id) ) : ?>

<div id="member-count" class="pag-count">
  <?php bp_group_member_pagination_count() ?>
</div>

<div id="member-pagination" class="pagination-links">
<?php bp_group_member_pagination() ?>
</div>

<ul id="member-list" class="item-list">
<?php while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); ?>

<li>
  <!-- Example template tags you can use -->
  <?php bp_group_member_avatar() ?>
  <?php bp_group_member_link() ?>
  <?php bp_group_member_joined_since() ?>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting! Looking at the bp_group_has_members it allows to to pass only single group using the group_id parameter when my first thought was that it would be able to pass an array of groups.
using your method you will need to run the loop multiple times in order to get the results you want. 
What i'd suggest is first getting the groups id of the logged in user as you did above:

```
$user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
$groups = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_ids( $user_id );
$groups = $groups['groups'];
```

or using a direct SQL statement which i believe will be faster:

```
$groups = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT group_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bp_groups_members WHERE user_id = %d",$user_id),0);
```

Then getting all the uses belong to the each of the groups using a direct SQL statement:

```
global $wpdb;

$allUsers = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bp_groups_members WHERE group_id IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($groups), '%s')).")",$groups),0);
```

and display the results using regular bp_has_members() loop while including the array of the users id that we got from the SQL statement above:

```
<?php if ( bp_has_members( array( 'include' => $allUsers ) ) ) : ?>

    <?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

        <li>
            user info....

        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can take a look [here](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/loops-reference/the-members-loop/) to see the bp_has_memebrs loop and to get all the functions you need in order to display the information you want.

Comment: Hey Eyal,great job! That do the trick!!!! Actually I have the problem, that it lists all names of the members, but not the avatars etc.: <?php bp_group_member_avatar() ?>
  <?php bp_group_member_link() ?>
  <?php bp_group_member_joined_since() ?>

Comment: You are welcome. And you are having the issue because you are now using the bp_has_members() loop instead of bp_group_has_members(). I edited the answer and added a link at the end that will take you to the codex page of bp_has_member where you can see all its functions.